# How can I bind Shift+PgUp to a key in zsh?

Tags: terminal, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

I know I can bind keys in my `.zshrc` like

```
bindkey '^[u' "echo hi^J"
```

I want to bind a command to make the terminal scroll up, like when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>. How can I do it? My terminal is Alacritty.

Comment: Makes more sense to bind that in the Terminal Emulator imo.

Comment: You are right! I found the solution for Alacritty: https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/pull/2089#issuecomment-477695741

Comment: @AdrianLopez So, how about you close this question, then?

Comment: I posted a solution for alacritty/tmux. I'll keep it open in case someone want to add solutions for other terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tillyboy pointed, this must be solved in the settings of every terminal. This is what solved it on my machine.

**ALACRITTY**

```
keybindings:
  - { key: P,          mods: Alt,   action: ScrollPageUp,   mode: ~Alt         }
  - { key: U,          mods: Alt,   action: ScrollPageDown, mode: ~Alt         }
```

**TMUX**

```
# scroll / copy mode (using alt+u, alt+p and movement keys
bind-key -n M-u copy-mode 
bind-key -n M-p copy-mode 
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi h send-keys -X cursor-left 
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi j send-keys -X cursor-down 
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi k send-keys -X cursor-up 
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi l send-keys -X cursor-right 
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi z send-keys -X page-down 
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi x send-keys -X page-up 
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Escape send-keys -X cancel
```